# How to expand div to take remaining width without using overflow: hidden method?

Tags: html, css, expand

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%;">
   <div id="left1" style="float:left; width:100px;">float left</div>
   <div id="left2" style="float:left; width:100px;">float left</div>

   <div id="remaining">Remaining width</div>
</div>
```

How to expand last div (#remaining)div to take remaining width **without using overflow: hidden method???** Any other method using :before & :after???

check this image.. i want exactly like the second layout
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6DvH.jpg

Comment: You have a typo `class=` should be `style`.

Comment: Please don't use overflow hidden /auto on parent div, because box-shadow / CSS transform get clipped when the parent (or other ancestor) element has overflow applied.

Comment: Please learn how to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It appears that you have commented on multiple answers that you want their solutions to look identical to your screenshot, yet you do not provide sufficient styles to replicate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change your `class` attribute to `style` attribute for inline styling.

and also you can't have two elements with the same ID. Id is always unique. So you need to change the id of your 2nd div to something else like (left2)

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%;">
   <div id="left" style="float:left; width:100px; color:white; background:blue;">float left</div>

   <div id="middle" style="float:left; width:100px; color:white; background:red;">float left</div>

   <div id="right" style=" color:white; background:green;">Remaining width</div>
</div>
```

Working Fiddles here...

**[DEMO fiddle with styles](http://jsfiddle.net/jokers/v61c2rjg/2/)**

**[DEMO fiddle with css](http://jsfiddle.net/jokers/6gd33187/1/)**

Another working demo as per your need. You need to add some padding on the left of `right` div to (exactly equal to the width of the divs that you have on the left of this div).

**[Demo Fiddle with new requirements](http://jsfiddle.net/jokers/6gd33187/2/)**

Comment: pls check this image.. i want exactly like the 2nd layout 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/g6DvH.jpg

Comment: Add padding-left:200px (equals to the width of 2 divs that you have on the left side of this div).... Here is a [Working FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jokers/6gd33187/2/).

Comment: i already tried this...i can't apply a fixed padding. i need a solution using :before & :after or without using padding / margin. if i use overflow: hidden; on parent my problem solved. but i don't wanna wrap child elements inside a hidden div, because box-shadow / CSS transform get clipped when the parent (or other ancestor) element has overflow applied

Comment: also want a cross browser solution.. (ie8 +)

Answer (score 0):

you typed class instead of style. otherwise you're fine:

```html
<div style="width:100%;background-color:red;">
  <div style="float:left; width:100px;background-color:green">float left</div>
  <div style="float:left; width:100px;background-color:blue">float left</div>

  <div style="background-color:yellow">Remaining width</div>
</div>
```

although you might also want to look into "display:inline-block"

Comment: I didn't even notice them. I removed them.

Comment: pls check this image.. i want exactly like the 2nd layout.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/g6DvH.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your id's have to be unique and the attribute for inline-style is "style".

```html
<div id="container" style="width:100%;">
   <div id="left" style="float:left; width:100px;">float left</div>
   <div id="middle" style="float:left; width:100px;">float left</div>
   <div id="right">Remaining width</div>
</div>
```

Comment: pls check this image.. i want exactly like the 2nd layout.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/g6DvH.jpg

Comment: You have to give them a height.

Comment: height should be auto.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this solution without using overflow property.

```html
<div style="height: 100px;background: green;float:left;width: 100px;"></div>
<div style="height: 100px;background: red;float:left;width: 100px;"></div>
<div style="height: 100px;background: yellow;width: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: pls check this image.. i want exactly like the 2nd layout.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/g6DvH.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="width: 100%; position: relative;" id="container">
  <div id="left" style="float: left; width: 100px; position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; background-color: #aaf">float left</div>
  <div style="float: left; width: 100px;  position: absolute; bottom: 0px; top: 0px; left: 100px; background-color: #b00;" id="middle">float left</div>
  <div style="margin-left:200px; background-color: #0b0" id="right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonum gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.y eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
    et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
  </div>
</div>
```

You have to change the position of the inner div's to absolute.